# Workflow with MVC 4 - EF 5 - SimpleMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, simplemembership

So I want to build an application with MVC 4 and Entity Framework 5. I've build simple applications before, but now I need some security around my current effort... I have some confusion / questions that I was hoping someone could answer;

First... Using the MVC 4 Internet Application Template it implements SimpleMembershipProvider. I have read every primary article about modification, implementation... However, this uses a Code-First implementation...
Problem: I have an existing database that I would like to import the scheme for to an EDMX database first approach... How do I implement the MVC 4 Simple membership provider when my database ties tightly and directly  into the user table (userid)?... I know I can use my own user table as long as i designate the userid and username fields as documented... Will this affect the provider, or the existing "AccountController" code? Will these need to be modified?

Second, what I am looking for is a workflow with this architecture... I am "old school" mostly database first approach... My project is a huge WIP (work in progress). I have a foundation, but will need to expand as needed... Can someone provide some insight into database first vs other approaches when there will be quite a bit of change management occurring?

Answer (score 0):

you can still use Code First to map to an existing database. You may need to explicitly map properties to table columns because the mappings do not follow the default conventions, but that doesn't prevent you from using Code First.

When transitioning from DB first to another mindset. Focus on how the objects interact with each other. then, at some point you will save the state of the objects after they interacted. This is where the ORM comes into play. detects changes and executes the necessary SQL statements to persist the current state of the objects.

Think of the database as just another storage container. In theory it could be replaced by another persistent storage mechanism (document db, file, persistent hash table, in memory list, etc.). In reality it's not that simple, but the idea of treating the DB as just a simple storage container helps to break away from the monolithic database concept that is/was ingrained into most devs.

But don't loose perspective of the design either. If it's a simple forms-over-data app where you will be adding features in the future than keep the design simple. than don't try to totally abstract the DB away. you know it's there and the relationship to the UI is almost 1:1, so take advantage of that.

In it's simplest form separation of concerns can be achieved by using the MVC controller to manage the interaction between the model (mapped to the DB via ORM) and the view (razor templates) my personal preference is to keep ORM out of the views so I typically query the database, map the domain model to a viewmodel and then pass the viewmodel to the view.

Again if it's a simple application and screens map directly to the database than viewmodel are probably overkill.